# Задание с предикативными единицами

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Нужно указать количество предикативных единиц и виды связи в сложном предложении:

Запах человеческих и лошадиных следов, пни, сложенные дрова и темная унавоженная дорога пугали ее: ей казалось, будто за деревьями в потемках стоят люди и где-то за лесом воют собаки.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что предикативная единица - это то же самое, что и простое предложение? 
Тогда получается, что предикативных единиц в данном предложении 5?

Запах человеческих и лошадиных следов/
Пни/
Сложенные дрова и темная дорога пугали её/
Воют собаки/ 
Стоят люди

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

[*Запах человеческих и лошадиных следов, пни, сложенные дрова и темная унавоженная дорога пугали ее]: **[ей казалось], (будто за деревьями в потемках стоят люди) и (где-то за лесом воют собаки).***

4 предикативные единицы. Это сложное предложение с разными видами связи, состоящее из 4 простых: 1 и 2 связаны между собой бессоюзной связью, вторая часть представляет собой сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя придаточными изъяснительными, соединёнными между собой однородной подчинительной связью.

В 1 предложении грамматическая основа **запах, пни, дрова и дорога пугали**, второе безличное, основа **казалось**, 3 - **стоят люди**, 4 -**воют собаки**.