# Определить главное предложение

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Помогите определить главное предложение:

Запах человеческих и лошадиных следов, пни, сложенные дрова и темная унавоженная дорога пугали её: ей казалось, будто за деревьями в потемках стоят люди и где-то за лесом воют собаки.

Я думаю, что главным предложением здесь является "ей казалось, будто за деревьями..." т.к. можно задать вопрос к придаточной части - /ей казалось (что?), будто за деревьями.../ Но как поступить с первой частью предложения: "Запах человеческих и лошадиных следов..."? 
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, отметьте его галочкой и стрелочкой вверх.

Answer (score 4):

***Запах человеческих и лошадиных следов, пни, сложенные дрова и темная унавоженная дорога пугали её*** — это предложение и является главным. Предложение ***ей казалось*** по отношению к первому является придаточным причины: *почему запах и т. д. пугали её? — потому что ей казалось*.

Смотрите ответ Людмилы на [Ваш вопрос с этим же предложением](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460328/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).

В этом ответе в квадратных скобках указаны два предложения с двоеточием (бессоюзной связью) между ними. Второе предложение (***ей казалось***) является главным для двух придаточных, выделенных круглыми скобками.